# Using Excel VBA to remotely run a code inside Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, excel, vba, ssh, raspberry-pi

I am trying to run a python script located inside my Raspberry Pi from my Excel. For example a simple 2 button excel page where you write the pause time between each run to a excel box, press the first button and the script runs. When you want it to stop, just press the second one.

First I started trying out the command prompt of windows 10 with built-in ssh. I created ssh keys from my laptop to the raspberry so there is no password asking.

```
C:\Users\xx>ssh pi@192.168.x.xx /home/pi/Temp_Codes/Script_Manual.py
Writing to database... Write Complete

C:\Users\xx>
```

This works perfectly and I know that the ssh connection is fine.

For the Excel part I am trying to use the shell method but there are some problems.

```
Sub RunScript()

    Dim PID As Variant

    PID = Shell("ssh pi@192.168.x.x /home/pi/Temp_Codes/Script_Manual.py", vbHide)

End Sub
```

This gives me a "Run-time error '53': File not found". I assume it is trying to find the script inside my computer instead of the raspberry pi. I tried different combinations but it is always the same error.

Comment: This is much too broad a question, especially since you've provided no code related to your actual question (how to SSH from VBA.) I'd suggest running a web server on the Pi would be much more sensible solution.

Comment: @miken32 I just edited the whole thing if you would like to take a look, and deleted what my general aim was, trying to learn stuff step by step now.

Comment: The error is likely because it can’t find the program. Try providing a full path to the `ssh` executable. You will probably have to specify the path to your public key as well.

Comment: But what I can't understand is the ssh command works perfectly when run from command prompt directly. I just want to have excel make cmd execute that line. I created a .cmd file with that single line. When I double click it, it still works perfectly. Then I tried to make excel run that file, still the same error. The path is the full path in my Raspberry Pi as well, I assume if there was a problem, it would appear when running from cmd directly as well.

Comment: You have a path set when you are logged into a shell. It tells the shell where to look for executables. When you’re running commands directly you don’t get that assistance.